# Creating a custom function that only runs in the sheet it's used it?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I've created a custom function in a module so I can use it in Excel. I've found it works fine except if I go to another tab and enter in some kind of data the function runs from the other tab off the current tab so I get incorrect data.

How do I make it so it will only run if the activesheet contains the custom function? I tried:

```
If Not ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets(4).Name Then Exit Function
```

which stops it from running on another sheet, but this is only a bandaid since when you go back to the seat with the function, it shows 0 and you have to run the function again to get the correct data. This also limits it to using it in just 1 sheet. How do I make it so the fuction only uses the current worksheet it's a part of? There has to be a way as normal formulas work like this.

Edit: Here is the code -

```
Function Indexm(asrng As Range, Mrng As Range, Crng As Range)
For Each cell In asrng
    If cell.Value2 Like Mrng.Value2 & "*" Then
        If IsEmpty(Indexm) Then
            Indexm = Trim(Cells(cell.Row, Crng.Column).Value2)
        Else
            Indexm = Trim(Cells(cell.Row, Crng.Column).Value2) & ", " & Indexm
        End If
    End If
Next
End Function
```

So the asrng is the search index, Mrng is what I'm matching (starting with...), and Crng is the return value I want. The for loop runs through the index and it adds each match to Indexm, seperated by a comma if there's more than 1 match,  then finally back to the cell that calls the function.

Comment: `If Not Application.Caller.Parent.Name = Sheets(4).Name Then Exit Function` or if the function is in a worksheet module then `If Not Application.Caller.Parent.Name = Me.Name Then Exit Function`

Comment: Please add the entire function you probably have some unqualified references

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem.  Probably using implicit ActiveSheet, and not passing all required data as parameters

Comment: This is something I did at work and I'm home for the weekend. The function basically does an index match for all matches instead of just the first which is why I created it in the first place. The problem is custom functions, as far as I've seen and read, only work from modules which is where it resides. Thanks Tim for the suggestion. I'll have to try it out. Thanks everyone for the responses.

Comment: _custom functions, as far as I've seen and read, only work from modules which is where it resides_ No, this is not true.  When you can, post your code and well show you where the issues are

Comment: Added code and description to OP. The `Application.Caller.Parent.Name` isn't working. I tried to debug.print for it and I get an error. Same with `Me.Name`

Comment: Is there a way to see how the default excel functions are coded? I was thinking of using a with statement which should be able to keep everything on the right sheets/workbook.